# Maven POM file not found in AzureDevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, devops, pom.xml

I get the following error:
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArECs.png)

It says that the POM file can't be found. I have my yaml file within my github project like this:
[Project picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlnSR.png)

My yaml file looks like this:
In my github there is a pom file in a folder called dataops/poms/pom.xml so i don't know why it can't find it.

```
    # Talend CI/CD on Azure DevOps
# Build Pipeline for building and publishing on Talend Cloud

trigger: none

pool:
 vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
- group: Talend Configuration
- name: project_name
  value: 'DataOps'
- name: job_name
  value: 'Soccer_api_Call'
- name: job_version
  value: '0.1'

steps:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: settings_xml
    inputs:
      secureFile: settings.xml

  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: license_txt
    inputs:
      secureFile: license.txt

  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
        mavenPomFile: '$(project_name)/poms/pom.xml' 
        mavenOptions: |
          -Dlicense.path=$(license_txt.secureFilePath)
          -Dupdatesite.path=$(UPDATESITE_PATH)
          -Dservice.url=$(CLOUD_URL)
          -Dcloud.publisher.screenshot=true
          -Xmx3096m -Xmx1024m
        options: '--settings $(settings_xml.secureFilePath) -Pcloud-publisher -pl jobs/process/$(job_name)_$(job_version) -am'
        goals: 'deploy'
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, in general prefer code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend you can try to use the `mavenPomFile: 'DATAOPS/poms/pom.xml'` instead of the `mavenPomFile: '$(project_name)/poms/pom.xml'`.
On my test, I create a demo like your yaml, and it works well with the full path:
[image]
[image]

Please ignore the test result, it just uses to check if the task can find the pom.xml.

Comment: Thankyou! that fixed it! but now i get the following error: [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: jobs/process/Soccer_api_Call_0.1. do you know what this means?

Comment: This looks like the issue happens on your task option: options: '--settings $(settings_xml.secureFilePath) -Pcloud-publisher -pl jobs/process/$(job_name)_$(job_version) -am'. What do you mean '-pl jobs/process/$(job_name)_$(job_version)'